# VirtualBox Show button does not show running virtual machines

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running VirtualBox 6.1.12, and after running the VMs there, if by any chance the Virtual machine closes, I cannot reopen it by clicking the SHOW button. However, in the preview, I can see that the machines are running. I usually access VBox from MobaXterm, and sometimes I get the error regarding "network" and that causes the Virtualbox problem. Is there any way that I can fix this issue? I tried re-installing both MobaXterm and Virtualbox too.

Comment: any chance did you find a solution ? my show button also is not working

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I was starting the VM from Task Scheduler using "run with highest privileges".  I was not able to attach the GUI to it from the desktop app after that, even if I ran as Administrator.  In fact, I couldn't even view the GUI by stopping and restarting the VM until I disabled the Task Scheduler entry and rebooted.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Same issue here. This is very dumb though. Part of having virtual machines is to have them start up at reboot. Hopefully Oracle will address this in the future